# syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ',' or ')' エラーの原因教えてください。

Tags: laravel-5

現在、Laravelで開発をしているのですが、下記コードで

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get(‘/’,function(){return redirect(‘/tasks’);});
Route::get(‘/tasks’,‘TaskController@index’);
Route::post(‘/tasks’,‘TaskController@store’);
Route::delete(‘/tasks/{task}’,’TaskController@destroy’);

\URL::forceScheme(‘https’);
```

Answer (score 2):

ご質問に掲載のコードではシングルクオート(`'`, U+0027, APOSTROPHE)になるべきところが、左シングルクオート(`‘`, U+2018, LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK)になってしまっているようです。(Webサイトに文字化けしたコードが掲載されていたり、使っているエディタやブラウザの機能で勝手に変換されることもあるようです。)

VS Codeでは、そのような間違いがあると同じ表示「syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ',' or ')'」になった(他のエラーは無視されて…)ので、質問をアップロードする時の文字化けではなく、実際にソースコードの中で間違われているのだと思います。

エディタの一括置換等を用いて全ての左シングルクオート(`‘`)を正しいシングルクオート(`'`)に置き換えて試してみてください。両者の表示上の違いは非常にわかりにくいですが、フォントをいろいろ変えながら見直せば、見えてくると思います。